# Placing a widget below the page title in storefront - woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, widget, storefront

I would like to place a widget (products filter) just below the page title (category page).
The existing widget "below header" appear just above the title actually... so I can't use it.
I use storefront theme and woocommerce.
Wordpress version: 5.8.2
Talk about category page where the products are displayed. I think you can call it a shop page. Not a regular page with only text...
Anyone can please share the right code?
Thanks!

Comment: please share the version of woocommerce. and are you talking product single page title of some page title/ shop page?

Comment: Hi @Ravi , Wordpress version: 5.8.2 Talk about category page where the products are displayed. I think you can call it a shop page. Not a regular page with only text... –